# Selenium click() without waiting for page to load Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a Python program to aid in getting a reservation on a website. I know the specific time a reservation will become available.
I hope to use Selenium to accomplish this. My strategy is to open 10 separate browser windows and then have them click "submit" at 0.1second intervals starting .02 seconds before the specific time the reservation is able to be made.
The problem I have is that each click() command seems to wait for the page to load before moving to the next click() command. Is it possible to click() and then move on to the next command without waiting for the page to load? The pages will load because they are in different windows, and I plan on interacting with them manually after that. Here's what I have. I want the click() commands to fire immediately but they don't.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser1 = webdriver.Firefox()
browser1.get('http://www.reservationsite.com')

browser2 = webdriver.Firefox()
browser2.get('http://www.reservationsite.com')

browser3 = webdriver.Firefox()
browser3.get('http://www.reservationsite.com')

def firstclick():
    elem1 = browser1.find_element_by_id('btnbookdates').click()
    return

def secondclick():
    elem2 = browser2.find_element_by_id('btnbookdates').click()
    return

def thirdclick():
    elem3 = browser3.find_element_by_id('btnbookdates').click()
    return

firstclick()
secondclick()
thirdclick()
```

Comment: I would guess you can't find an element by id before a page loads.

Comment: The pages are all loaded before the click(), it's the waiting for the next page to load (after the click() that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I can't see any second clicks in your code? I can see three first clicks.

Comment: Sorry, after firstclick() the program waits for the subsequent page to load before it moves to secondclick(). I want it to move immediately to secondclick(), essentially firing all 3 click()s at the same time. Then each of the three subsequent pages could load simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You can try loading Firefox with [`unstable` load strategy](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#-Beta-_load_fast_preference) (not tested):

> There is beta feature to make firefox not wait for the full page to
>   load after calling .get or .click. This may cause immediate find's to
>   break, so please be sure to use an implicit or explicit wait too. This
>   is only available for Firefox and not other browsers.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Combine it with an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html) to find the element by id:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnbookdates"))
)
element.click()
```

---

As an alternative and a bit "crazy" option would be to use [`sikuli`](http://www.sikuli.org/) screen automation tool to click at the specified image (screenshot of a button, for example) or at the specified coordinates on the screen.

Comment: The pages are all fully loaded before i submit the first click() so there is no problem finding the element. I am having to wait for the subsequent page to load after the first click() before it will go to the next click() command. I want to fire all of the click()'s then let those subsequent pages load at the same time.